# How to style a Group background in Windows / Phone 8.1 ListView?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have a ListView binding to grouped data. What I would like is to be able to bind the background of each group based on the content of the item. GroupStyle.ContainerStyle was deprecated in 8.1 without changing the ItemsPanel of the ListView. This unfortunately comes with a performance hit though.

Is there a way for me to define a background for the entirety of a Group without changing the ItemsPanel of the ListView?

Unfortunately, I can't change the template of the items and header together (though I've tried) because some of the items are duplicated and do not know which group they are in.

Comment: Could you use a converter do detect in which group is a particular item?

Comment: Unfortunately that would be quite difficult I think, or at the very least very costly. I'd have to put it in the item container and then have the converter parse the visual tree upwards until it finds the source of the `ItemsControl`. It would have to do this for each and every item, which (I believe) removes the benefit of using the new `ItemsPanel`, so I might as well use the old one. That's an idea I have considered though.

Comment: You can have GroupStyleSelector for overcome your need.

Comment: How will that help though? Each GroupStyle seemingly can only define a header template.

Comment: I think having a `BackgroundBrush` property (better than a converter) in your entity vm is the only option here. I doubt it would be any costly as the `ListView` will only render what's in the view.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different approaches to solve this problem:

- add the responsible Property to your ItemTemplate and connect it with a converter, which converts it to a type you need (in your case a BackgroundColor). The problem is, as already mentioned, that this is very costly and in my opinion a converter is not made for such a huge operation. Don't forget that in MVVM the **ViewModel should provide all the information** which is **needed by the one who designs the view**.
- **the better way is** to add a Property which is called something like “ItemBackground” and which you bind to the ItemTemplate. I prefer this approach, because there is no logic which background to use in the View.

Comment: But the problem is drawing the background across the whole group. I can solve for getting the control the information it needs.